# Как исключить название полей при сериализации

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Как используя Json.Net ограничить вывод названия полей.
Из такого формата

```
{
  “name“: “John“,
  “age“: 25,
  “interests“: [
    “bike“, “singing“
  ]
}
```

В такой

```
{25|”John”|[“bike“,”singing”]}
(Fields order by their names)
```

Comment: Ваш второй формат `{25|”John”|[“bike“,”singing”]}` это не json.

Comment: С помощью JSON.NET — никак, потому что то что вы хотите получить это не json. Реализуйте сериализатор самостоятельно. Только обратно такую структуру десериализовать будет невозможно

Comment: Это учебное задание? Какую именно задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Почему не как ответ?